# how to select lines containing several words using sed?

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I am learning using sed in unix.
I have a file with many lines and I wanna delete all lines except lines containing strings(e.g) alex, eva and tom.
I think I can use

```
sed '/alex|eva|tom/!d' filename
```

However I find it doesn't work, it cannot match the line. It just match "alex|eva|tom"...
Only

```
sed '/alex/!d' filename
```

works.

Anyone know how to select lines containing more than 1 words using sed?

plus, with parenthesis like "sed '/(alex)|(eva)|(tom)/!d' file" doesn't work, and I wanna the line containing all three words.

Comment: maybe you need the parenthesis?

Comment: @sam092 it doesn't work even if I use " sed '/(alex)|(eva)/!d' file ".

Comment: sorry my previous comment was no relevant. So you mean you want all three words but not either of them? any specific order of the words?

Comment: @sam092 yes, there is alreayd an answer, but it seems doesn't match 'all'.

Comment: simply because `|` is supposed to mean "or"

Comment: @sam092 yeah I realize it, so do you know how can i select the line with all three words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> delete all lines except lines containing strings(e.g) alex, eva and tom

As worded you're asking to preserve lines containing all those words but your samples preserve lines containing any.  Just in case "all" wasn't a misspeak: Regular expressions can't express any-order searches, fortunately sed lets you run multiple matches:

```
sed -n '/alex/{/eva/{/tom/p}}'
```

or you could just delete them serially:

```
sed '/alex/!d; /eva/!d; /tom/!d'
```

The above works on GNU/anything systems, with BSD-based userlands you'll have to insert a bunch of newlines or pass them as separate expressions:

```
sed -n '/alex/ {
          /eva/ {
            /tom/ p
        }
     }'
```

or

```
sed -e '/alex/!d' -e '/eva/!d' -e '/tom/!d'
```

Comment: Thank you, but shell throw an error says "extra characters at the end of p command".

Comment: delete serially is good, but your version doesn't works for unknown reason. I found I can "sed -e '/alex/!d' -e '/eva/!d' -e /tom/!d file"

Comment: Okay, try putting linebreaks after each `{` and before each `}`, and replace the `;`'s with newlines. What version of `sed` do you have?

Comment: Well I test it in my mac air's shell, guess it's due to version of shell

Answer (score 3):

sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line, for anything else just use awk:

```
awk '/alex/ && /eva/ && /tom/' file
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `\|` instead of `|`.

Edit: Looks like this is true for some variants of sed but not others.

Comment: It won't work either, like this: sed '/alex\|evva\|tom/!d' filename

Comment: Worked for me. I'm using GNU sed, version 4.2.1.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
 sed -r '/alex|eva|tom/!d' filename
```

OR on Mac:

```
 sed -E '/alex|eva|tom/!d' filename
```

Use `-i.bak` for inline editing so:

```
 sed -i.bak -r '/alex|eva|tom/!d' filename
```

Comment: Thanks it works! But I need a line with all these three words not one or two of them, "sed -E '/alex&eva&tom' filename" won't work, is there any other way to do?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nr '/alex/G;/eva/G;/tom/G;s/\n{3}//p' file
```

This method would allow a range of values to be present i.e. you wanted 2 or more of the list then use:

```
sed -nr '/alex/G;/eva/G;/tom/G;s/\n{2,3}//p' file
```